# PWA - hiding address bar on iPhone

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

After installing App on the home screen and running it, any link I click on takes me to the Safari, unlike on Android.

Rather then me re-developing PWA to work as a single page site, is there a jquery snipper which will replace body on the page with content from the other page?

---

To date, the easiest thing that I have found is by using something like below. The script would load required URL within the body of the page. You would need to have some type of a loading state and for the best performance, the endpoint must exclude any repetitive scripts/styles that were loaded on initial load.

```
        $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            if($(this).attr("href") == "#") {
                return;
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            $('body').load( $(this).attr("href"), function( response, status, xhr ) {
                if ( status == "error" ) {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error loading your page: ";
                    console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem/issue? What is your desired behaviour/result?

Comment: idea is to remove the address bar when used on iPhone. As far is a see, the only way, to achieve this we need to have a single page app. Because what i have done is not a single page app am looking for a simple solution to my problem.